# How do I hide 'recent content'?

Tags: 7, nodes

On each article page I have an annoying 'recent content' part underneath the articles written, along with an extra title (see screenshot). Is there a way to not show the recent content? (I've just started out so if the answer could not involve code that would be great) I've had this issue from the start, as far as I remember, and I've changed themes a few times, which didn't help. Display Suite doesn't do anything to hide / change position either.

That extra title by the way, also appears on the basic pages--only then it's the only title and it's still on the bottom of the page.

I'd be ever so happy if someone could help me out. Thanks in advance! :)

http://img560.imageshack.us/img560/5093/recentcontent.png

Comment: recent content might be generated by a contributed module; if so you need to disable that module. If recent content is a block you need to disable the block. If recent content is custom code so I don't think it easy to solve it without looking at source code.

Comment: What modules could those be for example? (the contributed modules you mentioned) Because I looked for 'contributed' and couldn't find any. :)

Comment: I'm note sure! Maybe you have a custom built modules! another suggestion; is to check if you have recent content view in views `admin/structure/views`; if so try to disable it.

Comment: I couldn't find views, so maybe I don't have that? However, turns out I had a block I needed to disable indeed--very stupid haha! Got me to solve the second title problem too, cause my content was in  the 'top content' block, so I changed that to 'content'. However, now 2 titles are showing up in articles. :(

Comment: *edit* Fixed that too with the manage display option. Thank you! :D

Comment: the second title should be in your page template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look under `admin/structure/block` and check if there's a block that's set to show in your Content region.

Comment: It was a block indeed! Duh! I can't believe I didn't realise that block corresponded with the problem... Thanks for pointing it out. Got me to solve the second title problem too, cause my content was in  the 'top content' block, so I changed that to 'content'. However, now 2 titles are showing up in articles. :(

Comment: *edit* Fixed that too with the manage display option. Thank you! :D